# Do you have an answer to my intermittent misfire issue

Tags: subaru

Will 1 open spark plug wire cause two cylinders not to fire on a wasted spark ignition system .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by "open"? Is that by pulling one spark plug lead? Could it be your one cylinder is bad (not firing) on one cylinder, then when you pull the 2nd cyl you now have two? Please further explain so we can more easily help you.

Comment: Are you sure the spark plug wire is open?  If it's closed/shorted, it could cause the coil not to be able to spark the sister cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

after further diagnosis when one cylinder goes down it does indeed take out its sister cylinder with it . I found that my coil had an intermittent internal short causing no spark to 2 cylinders.  Change out the coil and now all 4 cylinders contributing and purrs like a kitten